# What would be an example of a convex set in one dimension?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

How can such a set exist in one dimension? What would this look like geometrically? I recently started learning about convex sets and I don't know how to visualise one in 1-dimension. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Intervals are the only examples of convex sets in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: An interval. (In one dimension convex = connected.)